# How do I call individual methods from a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

In the javascript assets file I have a `jstester.js` file like this:

```
function hehe()
{
    alert("wedsdsd");
}
document.write("fdygsdfysdgf");
```

Then in the `public index.html` file I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/assets/jstester.js">
hehe();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I thought that is how I can call a method from my Javascript file but looks like it is not working, no message box shows up... So what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: is it even a good practice or no?

Comment: And you got your script reference and script block mixed up

Comment: hmm? can you explain more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `<script>` has a `src` then the text content of the element will be ignored.
so you can't do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jstester.js">
  hehe();
</script>
```

but:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jstester.js"></script>
<script>hehe();</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you looking for:

```
<body>
    <script src="/assets/jstester.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">hehe();</script>
</body>
```